# Find the differential equation corresponding to family of curves $y=c(x-c)^2$, where c is an arbitrary constant

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the differential equation corresponding to family of curves $y=c(x-c)^2$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant

**My attempt:**
$$y=c(x-c)^2 \implies \sqrt y = \sqrt c (x-c)$$

Differentiating, $$\frac{y'}{2\sqrt y} = \sqrt c \implies  c = \frac{(y')^2}{4 y}$$

Substituting value of $c$ in above given equation i get

then i am getting differential equation as

$$64y^4 = y'^2(4xy-y'^2)^2  \tag{1}$$

But if i differentiate above given equation

$$y'=2c(x-c) \implies c = x-\frac{2y}{y'}$$

With this i get

$$y'^3=4y(xy'-2y)\tag{2}$$

Now which one is correct - (1) or (2)?

Comment: $8y^2=4xyy'-y'^3$ gives rise to the Clairaut form $u=xu'-u'^3$ for $u=\pm\sqrt{y}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when we are given a differential equation containing $n$ arbitrary constants, by differentiating it successively $n$ times and eliminating the constants gives us the required differential equation of **order $n$**.

Here, $n=1$. Simplifying $(1)$ by taking the square root, we get: $$8y^2 = y’(4xy-y’^2) \implies y’^3=4xyy’-8y^2 = 4y(xy’-2y)$$ that is $(2)$.

Note that, simplifying $(1)$ gave us the simplest form of the differential equation. But, it is always preferred to differentiate the equation and eliminate constants.

Comment: -ve equation is to ignored is it? thank you for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Both of your solutions are correct. Here is my attempt to find the solution.   Note that $y'/y = 2/(x-c)$, therefore $$c=x-2y/{y'}$$ Substitute in $$y'=2c(x-c)$$ and we get $${y'}^3=4y(xy'-2y)$$